# How to understand the first line of the DCPU-16 specs assembly example?

Tags: assembly, dcpu-16

I am trying to understand the [specs](http://0x10c.com/doc/dcpu-16.txt), but fail to understand the first line of the example given:

```
SET A, 0x30              ; 7c01 0030
```

Here is what I understood from the specs:

- the first word (7c01) fully defines the instruction
- the operator is 0x1 which is the command `SET a, b`
- b = 111100 = 0x3C (when I convert into Hex) = literal value 0x3C
- a = 000000 = register A

So I understand the instruction as SET A, **0x3C**

Can anyone advise where I go wrong?

Comment: Where does b = 111100 come from? From my point of view b = 110000 = 0x30...

Comment: @cli_hlt Hum, now I have 0x7c01 = 0111110000000001 which gives me b=011111=1F  ?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah ok from the comments I finally got my answer.

You are missing the "Values" section from the spec, there it says:

```
Values:
....
0x1f: next word (literal)
```

So we have:

```
0x7c01 = 0111110000000001

0001 = SET
000000 = register A
011111 = 1F -> next word -> [PC++]
```

Next word is `0x0030`... voilà.

Answer (score 1):

@cli_hlt is almost correct

dcpu documentation says:

> In a basic instruction, the lower five bits of the first word of the
> instruction are the opcode, and the remaining eleven bits are split
> into a five bit value b and a six bit value a.
>
> b is always handled by the processor after a, and is the lower five
> bits. In bits (in LSB-0 format), a basic instruction has the format:
> aaaaaabbbbbooooo

so the correct answer is:

```
0x7c01 = 0111110000000001

00001 = SET
00000 = register A
011111 = 1F -> next word -> [PC++]
```